# Organo Charts with Python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, charts

I'm trying to build some [organogram charts](http://www.virtualcampuses.eu/images/1/13/Organogram_hibernia.jpg) and I was wondering if is there any way to do this with python. e.g reading data from .csv file and building the chart?

Comment: Have you read this post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738288/displaying-networkx-graph-with-labels

Comment: Thanks Rob, I haven't